# How to POST with XML payload in node-red

Tags: xml, escaping, node-red

Just starting to work with node-red and having trouble getting XML loaded into a javascript object msg.payload that node-red needs for sending a post request to my server.

My API is looking for the following:

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <userRequest>
      <authentication>
          <username>foo</username>
          <password>bar</password>
      </authentication>
      <action>doit</action>
  </userRequest>
```

But without escaping the XML, I can't get it loaded into the object.  And I can't find the right way to escape it.

Advice?

So far I've tried to escape the XML in various ways to get it past the JS parser in node-red, but nothing seems to work.  Node-red always complains that there is an error in the code.

There are examples of it outputting XML, but nothing about how to send XML payloads on a POST to an external serve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To POST XML, you need to ensure you set the `content-type` header to `application/xml`. For example, using a Function node:

```
msg.payload = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><userRequest<authentication><username>foo</username><password>bar</password></authentication><action>doit</action></userRequest>';
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers['content-type'] = 'application/xml';
return msg;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  The request works for me now after trying what you suggested. But it turns out the headers weren't needed. The problem was that the password I was using had escape characters in it and the errors I was getting didn't point clearly to that.  But using your request formatting helped me find that error.